# Is there a reason why Harmonic functions are defined on open sets?

Tags: complex-analysis, differential-geometry, differential-topology, harmonic-functions

Whenever I see a definition of a harmonic function, it's always defined as follows

> A function $f : U \to \Bbb{R}$ is called harmonic (where $U$ is an open subset of $\Bbb{R}^n$) iff it is twice continuously differentiable on $U$ and satisfies Laplace's equation $\Delta f = 0$.

- Is there a reason why $U$ is always chosen to be open and what are the ramifications if $U$ is chosen to not be an open set in the context of the Laplace operator (in which we take the second partial derivatives)?

**Edit:** I have recently read that for a "good" subset $V$ of $\Bbb{R}^n$ i.e. a submanifold of codimension 1 with boundary, we can extend the notion of differentiability by extending $V$ for any point $v \in V$ to involve a neighbourhood around $v$ over which we can differentiate. Then the derivative of $V$ is just the derivative of the extension.

- Supposedly, unless $V$ is "good", then the derivative needn't be uniquely defined. Why does this happen to be the case and what's the necessity in defining "good" as we have done?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Probably: the Laplace operator involves derivatives; for differentiable functions, *by definition*, the domain is considered to be open set.

Comment: Whether looking at gravitational potential (or later electrostatic potential,) these functions satisfy Laplace's equation where there are no sources of potential, which would be in most of free space; and that context would have been one of the earlier applications of potential functions. That is, you would specify discrete sources or distributions of sources, and then solve for the potential in the remaining part of space.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'll be assuming the function is real valued (as it is in the problem) but some of what I say generalizes.

The domain of the function is presumed to be an open set because derivatives and the Laplacian are defined on open sets. The reason we need to use an open set as the domain for $f$ when talking about derivatives, is because the concept of a derivative doesn't make sense when considering a point in isolation: you need to look in the neighborhood of the point. If I told you that I have a function $f:\{0,1,2,3\}\to\mathbb{R}$ and wanted to know how do calculate $f'(x)$, you'd tell me I couldn't. The concept of the derivative of a discrete function makes no sense because the the concept of $$\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$$ doesn't make sense for such a function, since $f(x)$ is undefined for any value near $2$.

This is the core difficulty. Every closed set, $C$, in a metric space has the property that $\exists c\in C$ such that $\forall\varepsilon\exists x\in C^{c}$ such that $d(c,x)<\varepsilon$. This is immediate, because $C^c$ is open, so it doesn't contain its closure. Take $c$ to be some point in the closure of $C^c$ but not in $C$ and we are done.

In the particular case of the real numbers, although it's possible you'll have a one-sided limit you can calculate (say, in the example $[0,1]$), but the traditional definition of a derivative is the limit, not the one sided limit, and so you'll wind up with more differentiable functions than we normally have. Any time the left-handed limit doesn't exist, you will still get a derivative for $f(x)$ at $0$. For example, $f(x)=|x|$ is differentiable on $[0,1]$ under a one-sided limit.

Sometimes the above behavior is desirable, and so we wish to extend our notion of derivative to such places. There are two obvious ways to do this. For $f:A\to\mathbb{R}$ we can extend our definition of derivative to cover any point $x$ in the boundary of $A$ by considering the limit in the definition of a derivative to be a sequential limit, i.e.
$$f'(x)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{f(a_n)-f(a)}{a_n-x}$$ where $a_n$ is a sequence converging to $x$.

This definition can cause problems from being too general, as the derivative of a function on $\{0\}\cup\{\frac{1}{n}|n\in\mathbb{n}\}$ doesn't do what we are used to doing with derivatives, since there is no neighborhood or half neighborhood of any point on which $f$ is defined everywhere. The middle ground is to do as follows: Define the derivative of $f$ at a point, $a$ to be the number, $g(a)$, that satisfies
$$f(a + h) = f(a) + g(a) h + O(|h|^2)$$
For all $h>0$. Define the *function* $f'(x)$ to be the formal derivative of $f(x)$ to be the function that satisfies $f'(a)=g(a)$ and which is defined exactly where the above equality holds.

This definition encapsulates the sense in which a derivative is the linear approximation of a function and so is very useful. It also always satisfies the mean value theorem, if you have an interval $f'(x)$ is defined in.

Comment: I've added an extra section to do with submanifolds and extensions of differentiability. Could you possibly address those too if you're comfortable with the content?

Comment: Probabilists have a definition of harmonic and subharmonic that does not use differentiability at all, but is based on the value of a strong Markov process when it hits a certain set. This stems from the fact that traditional harmonic functions have such characterisation in terms of Brownian motion.

Comment: @khallil your edit surprises me, as for a point on the boundary I would think that you would always get either one value or an undefined limit, not two defined limits with different values. I added about limit extensions of derivatives, which are pretty common and Which I should have included from the start

Comment: Thanks for including the limit extension part, @StellaBiderman. May I ask why my edit surprised you?

Comment: For the reason I describe above: it seems counterintuitive that in two different neighborhoods you'd get different (but defined) values. The reason this surprises me is that the intersection of the two neighborhoods is an open set, and so it must contain an open ball. Extending the derivative on this ball should, in my intuition, match up with extending the derivative to a set containing this ball since derivative is a local property. But that would force the two extensions to have the same derivative (if they are both defined)

Comment: @khallil Is there more that you'd like me to add, or are you waiting to give out the bounty

Comment: Instead of awarding it prematurely, I'd really like to try and understand all the answers first and perhaps some insightful discussion can arise!

Answer (score 1):

Let $A\subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ and $$B(x_0,\epsilon):=\left\{x\big{|}|x-x_0|<\epsilon\right\}$$ and $$D(A):=\{x|(\forall \epsilon >0)((B(x,\epsilon)\setminus \{x\})\cap A\neq \emptyset)\}.$$
More generally you can choose $U$ satisfying the following conditions:
$$U\subset\mathbb{R}^n \,\ \text{ and } \,\ D(U)\subset U$$

Comment: May I ask what $D(A)$ represents?

Comment: The set of all limit points of $A$.

Comment: Also, may I ask why we desire the limit points to be inside of U? Does something important depend on this fact?

Comment: to mention derivation.

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean by derivation?

Comment: It is possible to define the derivative of a function having a domain more general than an interval (since the point $c$ need only be an elemnet of the domain and also a cluster point of the domain) but the significance of the concept is most naturally apparent for functions defined on intervals. (Introduction to Real Analysis, Robert G. Bartle&Donald Sherbert, Page 158)

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\Eps}{\varepsilon}\newcommand{\Reals}{\mathbf{R}}\newcommand{\Basis}{\mathbf{e}}$Let $U \subset \Reals^{n}$ be non-empty, $f:U \to \Reals$ a function, and $x_{0}$ a point of $U$.

As you know, the definition of *differentiability* of $f$ at $x_{0}$ involves a limit at $x_{0}$, which strictly speaking requires $f$ to be defined in some open ball centered at $x_{0}$.

If $x_{0}$ is instead a boundary point of $U$, you can attempt to define the derivative of $f$ at $x_{0}$ by extending $f$ differentiably in a neighborhood of $x_{0}$, i.e., picking a differentiable function $F$ in some ball $B$ about $x_{0}$ in such a way that $F = f$ in $B \cap U$, and *declaring* that $Df(x_{0}) = DF(x_{0})$. Of course, this idea only works if $Df(x_{0})$ does not depend on $F$.

In order for $Df(x_{0})$ not to depend on the choice of extension $F$, it's necessary that "some basis $(\Basis_{i})_{i=1}^{n}$ of $\Reals^{n}$ is tangent to $U$ at $x_{0}$". In this event, $f$ itself determines directional derivatives along elements of a basis, so a linear approximation of $f$ at $x_{0}$, if one exists at all, is unique.

To give precise definitions (that are quite likely not standard), say that a vector $\Basis$ is *tangent to $U$ at $x_{0}$* if there exists a smooth curve $\gamma:(-\Eps, \Eps) \to \Reals^{n}$ (for some value of *smooth*) such that:

- $\gamma(0) = x_{0}$;
- $\gamma'(0) = \Basis_{i}$;
- $\gamma(t) \in U$ for $0 < t < \Eps$. (N.b., not necessarily for $-\Eps < t < 0$.)

Say that a basis $(\Basis_{i})_{i=1}^{n}$ of $\Reals^{n}$ is *tangent to $U$ at $x_{0}$* if each element is tangent to $U$ at $x_{0}$.

If there exists a basis $(\Basis_{i})_{i=1}^{n}$ of $\Reals^{n}$ tangent to $U$ at $x_{0}$, and if $(\gamma_{i})_{i=1}^{n}$ is a corresponding collection of curves, say that $f$ is *differentiable at $x_{0}$* if:

- For each $i$, $f \circ \gamma_{i}$ is differentiable from the right at $0$, and
- If $\gamma:(-\Eps, \Eps) \to \Reals^{n}$ is an arbitrary smooth curve with $\gamma(0) = x_{0}$ and $\gamma(t) \in U$ for all $t \neq 0$, then $f \circ \gamma$ is differentiable at $0$. (This ensures that if both $\Basis$ and $-\Basis$ are tangent to $U$ at $x_{0}$, then the respective directional derivatives are compatible.)

It's straightforward to check that if $M \subset \Reals^{n}$ is an *open* submanifold (n.b., not codimension $1$) and $U = \overline{M}$ is a manifold with boundary, then at each boundary point of $U$ there is a basis tangent to $U$. (Take a basis of the tangent space to the boundary together with an inward-pointing normal vector.)

The preceding framework runs into trouble for sets such as the following:

- Submanifolds of lower dimension (e.g., plane curves).
- Closures of open sets with "sharp boundaries", such as
  $$
  U = \{(x, y) : |y| \leq x^{2}\}.
  $$
  (The origin is problematic; no vector with non-vanishing second component is tangent to $U$ at the origin.)

For all the generality one gains by this type of scheme (e.g., manifolds with corners, edge-of-the-wedge results), in elementary circumstances it's adequate, and much easier, simply to assume $U$ is open.